# Export/move an old version of a mediawiki template

Tags: templates, export, mediawiki, wiki

I have installed a MediaWiki and I would like to use infoboxes. Unfortunately my host does not allow lua and therefore the latest version of the infobox template does not run if I export it with Special:Export and move it to my wiki with Special:Import.

I would like to avoid using manual copy of the historical template code because all the dependencies make this approach very tedious to get it to work.

Therefore I would like to know how can I export an old version of a template i.e. a version that does not require LUA?

Comment: You would have to pick the right template version from the page history, check what dependencies it has, pick the right version for those, continue until there are no more dependencies... depending on the template, it could be a dozen iterations. I am not aware of any easier way. There are tools to the the same process when viewing an old version of a page (e.g. the [Memento](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Memento) extension), but they don't reimplement exporting.

Answer (score 1):

While this solution isn't as easy as the export, it should work.

1. Goto wikipedia's Template:Infobox Page.
2. Click on View History
3. Type 2011 into the "From Year" box  (Lua was deployed in 2012)
4. Click on the timestamp of the top result (or any other result)
5. Click on the View Source Tab at the top
   ---- Ensure that this copy does not contain #Invoke
6. Copy that source code into your own template.

you may need to do a bit more tweaking, or read through the source code and copy other templates manually, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I figured out this way too but it is very tedious since one cannot use the Special:Export function. I am looking for a simpler way.